# linear combination of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve for $\alpha _{i} $ in the Equation

$Y = \sum_{i} \alpha _{i} A_{i}$

where dimensions of Y are very large and Y and $ A _{i} $ are matrices

Comment: Please provide some specifics. The dimesnion of matrices, the limits of summation, etc. Otherwise the question is too broad to give a complete answer.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy:- dimensions are of type ( 1000 * 100) and upper limit of i is a finite number of the order of 100s

Comment: In general, if your matrices are $1000 \times 100$ and you have less than $100 \cdot 1000 = 100,000$ different matrices $A_i$, then for most matrices $Y$ there won't even be a solution because your system of equations would be over-determined.  Do you have a good reason to believe that there will be a solution for the $A_i$ and $Y$ that you'll be working with?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything special about matrices when it comes to simply multiplying by scalars or summing. These linear operations don't rely on matrix multiplication or anything that would be lost by instead thinking of these matrices as (very) long vectors.

Hence, we can solve the same way we would with vectors (reduce the matrix to echelon form and determine whether a solution exists and if so, whether it's unique and what it might be).

Note, however, @user2566092's remark about the chances that a solution would exist in the general case.